# Unable to make TLS TCP connection to remote MySQL server with PyMySQL, other tools work

Tags: python, ssl, pymysql

Setting up a new server that I want to communicate to a central MySQL database, using a TLS connection for security

Following steps like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04) I have been able to set up TLS for my MySQL server, I have made several users that are able to login from any host (%), and require SSL connections

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| user       | host      | ssl_type |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| testuser   | %         | ANY      |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

I can confirm this on any host by connecting using tools like HeidiSQL or the MySQL CLI tool
Ex: `mysql -u testuser -p -h mysql_server_IP` this will initiate a TLS connection, as confirmed by \s
This rules out the majority of issues I have seen on this and other forums, which is caused by the host being set to localhost.

When accessing local databases, the following works fine. When connecting to non-TLS remote database servers, it also works fine.

```
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                             user=user,
                             password=password,
                             db=db,
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

When attempting to access my server with require-tls I receive the following error
`pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'testuser'@'desktop.example.com' (using password: YES)")`

The other findings I have suggest that that error is caused by: 
Invalid username / password combinations, or, connection prohibited by that host. However I know I can make connections from this host, as demonstrated by the CLI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When connecting to a server that only has the `require_secure_transport = ON` in my.cnf, PyMySQL gives a more obvious error around being unable to start a TLS connection. `pymysql.err.InternalError: (3159, 'Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.'` But if the MySQL user itself requires SSL, you get the more generic permission denied error from the question above.

On the [github issue tracker](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/386) there is mention of supplying the CA .pem file. If you don't have access to these files and want to trust the self signed cert implicitly. The [docs](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html) mention the `-ssl` flag, which allows you to pass in paths for various cert files.

However, by passing in a valid dictionary, without any of the valid keys, you can effectively blanket trust self-signed certs. Example:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                             user=user,
                             password=password,
                             db=db,
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                             ssl={"fake_flag_to_enable_tls":True})
```

Comment: You are a life-saver. I looked so hard to bypass the darn SSL certificate and this was the only answer that explained how! Much appreciated.

Comment: Note that it's really bad idea to skip cert validation. Instead, you can either get a free cert from Let's Encrypt (for a domain you own), or you can add your self-signed cert to your code's trust store cert bundle so that the client can at least trust the server.

Answer (score 0):

For people getting this error while using Tortoise ORM, you have to use the verbose init structure:

https://tortoise.github.io/databases.html#passing-in-custom-ssl-certificates

```
# Here we create a custom SSL context
import ssl
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
# And in this example we disable validation...
# Please don't do this. Loot at the official Python ``ssl`` module documentation
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# Here we do a verbose init
await Tortoise.init(
    config={
        "connections": {
            "default": {
                "engine": "tortoise.backends.asyncpg",
                "credentials": {
                    "database": None,
                    "host": "127.0.0.1",
                    "password": "moo",
                    "port": 54321,
                    "user": "postgres",
                    "ssl": ctx  # Here we pass in the SSL context
                }
            }
        },
        "apps": {
            "models": {
                "models": ["some.models"],
                "default_connection": "default",
            }
        },
    }
)
```