# How do we pass SSL arguments to MySQL in Gramex's FormHandler?

Tags: mysql, database, ssl, gramex

I'm connecting to a [MySQL database](https://gramener.com/gramex/guide/formhandler/#supported-databases) for OTP using this `gramex.yaml` configuration:

```yaml
otp:
    url: 'mysql+pymysql://$USER:$PASS@$MYSQL_SERVER/$DB'
    table: $TABLE
```

Whe Gramex starts, it reports an Exception:

```
InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (3159, 'Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.')
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58396886/100904) suggests passing a dummy `ssl:` dict.

How do I pass this to Gramex's FormHandler?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities. If you don't have an SSL certificate to connect to the database, use:

```yaml
otp:
  url: 'mysql+pymysql://$USER:$PASS@$MYSQL_SERVER/$DB'
  table: $TABLE
  connect_args:
    ssl:
      fake_flag_to_enable_tls: true
```

If you have an SSL CA certificate in a PEM format, use:

```yaml
otp:
  url: 'mysql+pymysql://$USER:$PASS@$MYSQL_SERVER/$DB'
  table: $TABLE
  connect_args:
    ssl_ca: /path/to/ca-certificate.pem
```

You may pass any other parameter to the [pymysql connection object](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html).